# AngularJS: What is the equivalent to Ember.js' CollectionView?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently evaluating a few JavaScript frameworks and right now I'm working with AngularJS. I was wondering how I would go about accomplishing the equivalent to Ember.js' CollectionView in AngularJS? I can't seem to find what I'm looking for and I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Is `ng-switch` what I'm looking for? [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) **update** - don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think what you want is [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)

Comment: That gets me half-way there. To clarify, I need to also be able to test if a list is empty so I can display different markup.

Comment: create a other element with ng-show="array.length == 0", if the array is empty the ng-repeat won't create any element and the element with ng-show will be show

Comment: What's funny is that your comment was what I was looking for.